# File Upload using Selenium Webdriver and ruby with < button type="button">

Tags: html, ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver and Ruby and I need to automate the file upload feature. 
I tried with

`WAIT.until { driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonset').displayed? }`

by using this it gives time out error

```
  elem = driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonset')
  puts "Hi"
  js = <<-end
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    buttons[0].setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
end
  elem = driver.execute_script(js, elem)
  puts elem
  elem.send_keys("C:\\Users\\seema\\Desktop\\1413.jpg")
```

Above code is not working and script fails by following error

here is HTML code

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
      <button class="otherButtonClass ui-state-hover ui-state-focus" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <button class="otherButtonClass" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;">
      <button class="cancelButtonClass" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   </div>
</div>
```

here is error stack

```
,"message":"error - undefined me
    thod `send_keys' for nil:NilClass \n [\"tests/upload_branding.rb:38:in `create_publish_pla
    yer'\", \"tests/upload_branding.rb:80:in `PublishPlayerTest'\", \"org/jruby/RubyBasicObjec
    t.java:1703:in `__send__'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib
    /minitest/unit.rb:1258:in `run'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-rep
    orters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:62:in `run_with_hooks'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ru
    by/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:105:in `run'\", \"org/jruby/RubyProc.java:255
    :in `call'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:153:in `
    recursively_run_setup_and_teardown'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.
    2.4/lib/scope.rb:155:in `recursively_run_setup_and_teardown'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/
    gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:139:in `run_setup_and_teardown'\", \"c:/jruby-1.
    7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:105:in `run'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/li
    b/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `_run_suite'\", \"org/j
    ruby/RubyArray.java:2417:in `map'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4
    .7.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:926:in `_run_suite'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gem
    s/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporter_runner.rb:45:in `_run_suite'\", \"c:/jr
    uby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb:71:in `_r
    un_suites'\", \"org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2417:in `map'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/s
    hared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb:70:in `_run_suites'\", \"c:/jruby-
    1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporter_runner.rb
    :37:in `_run_suites'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/mini
    test/unit.rb:877:in `_run_anything'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest
    -4.7.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1085:in `run_tests'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/g
    ems/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporter_runner.rb:30:in `run_tests'\", \"org/
    jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1703:in `__send__'\", \"org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2209:in `send
    '\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1072:i
    n `_run'\", \"org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617:in `each'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/sh
    ared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1071:in `_run'\", \"c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/
    gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1059:in `run'\", \"tests/upload_brand
    ing.rb:87:in `(root)'\"]","result":false}
```

In IRB i found following errors

```
irb(main):038:0> Wait.until { $driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonse>button')[1].displayed? }
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: timed out after 80 seconds (Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.ui-dialog-buttonse>button"})}
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/wait.rb:57:in `until'
    from (irb):38:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1093:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1489:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
    from C:\jruby-1.7.4\/bin/jirb_swing:53:in `(root)'
```

also for second command

```
irb(main):043:0> elem = $driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonse>button')[1]
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.ui-dialog-buttonse>button"}
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/seema/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130704-2984-1wifg7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8444:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/seema/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130704-2984-1wifg7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8453:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/seema/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130704-2984-1wifg7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10456:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/seema/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130704-2984-1wifg7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10461:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/seema/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130704-2984-1wifg7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10401:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:607:in `execute'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:575:in `find_element_by'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
    from (irb):43:in `evaluate'
    from C:\jruby-1.7.4\/bin/jirb_swing:53:in `(root)'
```

Kindly help

Comment: give me the relevant `html` code here. Probably I can help you out.also paste the full error stack.

Comment: please paste the partial screen where to upload,I think this part is not sufficient to help. But don't remove the html from the post.

Comment: let me know if my suggestion help you or not,otherwise I would like to ask you other informations.

Answer (score 0):

First check out the link [`Selenium::WebDriver::Wait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Wait.html#until-instance_method) to avoid such time out error.

You can try the below code :

```
# implicit time out declarations
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 60)

# wait till the required button element being displayed
# Use the link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
# for css selectors
wait.until { driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonse>button')[1].displayed? }
elem = driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonse>button')[1]
elem.sendKeys("C://path/To/File.jpg")
```

**Update**

Looking at the link [`aria-disabled attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and your part `html` below, I am seeing `aria-disabled` is set as *false* :

```
<button class="otherButtonClass ui-state-hover ui-state-focus" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

That desired button element is disabled.

Now see the question : [`Does WebDriver support file uploads?`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?)

> You can't interact with the native OS file browser dialog directly, but we do some magic so that if you call WebElement#sendKeys("/path/to/file") on a file upload element, it does the right thing. Make sure you don't WebElement#click() the file upload element, or the browser will probably hang.

**Update**

```
#implicit time out declarations
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 60)

#wait till the div element is being displayed
wait.until { driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonse').displayed? }
elem = driver.find_element(:css,'div.ui-dialog-buttonse')

js = <<-end
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    buttons[0].setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
end

elem = driver.execute_script(js, elem) 
elem.sendKeys("C://path//To//File.jpg")
```

Comment: **Down-voter :** probably you know the correct answer,which is cleared to me,as you marked this answer as wrong. But I believe this should work. I would like to see what the atmost correct answer. Listen here all are learning, so only down-vote is not a good contribution at all. Either post an answer,or comment here to correct it if any thing wrong you observed. either way you can contribute. But only down-vote is not a good approach..

Comment: @seema  that means we are now being able to remove time-out error. So can you put now your updated code and error stack again with an **EDIT**.

Comment: Hi Priti,
I tried with your code i got this error message
error - Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with \n [\"[remote server] file:///C:/Us
ers/seema/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20130704-1412-12fnoke/extensions/fxdriver@go
oglecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7736:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible'\", \

Comment: @Priti , Will the slash (/) work with this upload command ? As far as I know two backslashes(\\) are generally required.

Comment: @kedar humm.. That was from copy and paste from OP code. That's not primary concern,thus I over looked. :) thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Priti still facing same problem :( I used your updated code.