# How can I make Selenium interact with a file input field with an opacity of 0?

Tags: css, ruby, selenium-webdriver

In the project I'm working on, we have a lot of file input fields with an opacity of 0.

if I have an input field wih an `id` of `file_upload` and `opacity:0`,

then `@driver.find_element(id: 'file-upload').send_keys full_file_path` will give me a `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError`

How can I successfully attach a file to this input?

Im am using selenium-webdriver for Ruby

Note:
I know that this is possible to do with Capybara but using Capybara is not currently an option in my project.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one element with provided Id??

Comment: yes, there is only one.

Comment: Try to wait until element visible then go for send_keys

Answer (score 0):

One option is to it with `execute_script` instead of `find_element.send_keys`:

```
full_file_path = "./path/'

script = <<-JS
  document.getElementById("#file-upload").val("#{full_file_path}")
JS

@driver.execute_script script
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I don't think you can programmatically change the value of a file input field.

Comment: it looks like it is possible. see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466737/file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-and-ruby-with-button-type-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466737/file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-and-ruby-with-button-type-button)

Answer (score 0):

The Java code, which is working fine.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"input[id*='upload']\").style.opacity='1'");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='upload']")).sendkeys(filepath);
```